# serializability java Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, serialization, parallel-processing, parfor

I use a toolbox written in Java javaplex [https://github.com/javaplex/javaplex.github.io][1]

the link for the input matrix mat [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3uM9Np2kJYoTmtkRHV2WU5JeGc/view?usp=sharing][3]
the first loop which is working very good is for

```
cd C:\ProjetBCodesMatlab\Jplex
javaaddpath('./lib/javaplex.jar');
import edu.stanford.math.plex4.*;

javaaddpath('./lib/plex-viewer.jar');
import edu.stanford.math.plex_viewer.*;

cd './utility';
addpath(pwd);
cd '..';

max_dimension = 3; 
max_filtration_value = 1000; 
num_divisions = 10000;
options.max_filtration_value = max_filtration_value;
options.max_dimension = max_dimension - 1;

%------------------------------------------------------------
for i=1:10
         maColonne = mat(i,:); 
         intervals= Calcul_interval(maColonne,options,max_dimension, max_filtration_value, num_divisions)
         intervals 
         multinterval{i}= intervals;    
 end
```

I use a I7 when I execute the function feature('numCores');

```
MATLAB detected: 4 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 8 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 8 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 4 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.
```

I run the same code with parfor

```
cd C:\ProjetBCodesMatlab\Jplex
javaaddpath('./lib/javaplex.jar');
import edu.stanford.math.plex4.*;

javaaddpath('./lib/plex-viewer.jar');
import edu.stanford.math.plex_viewer.*;

cd './utility';
addpath(pwd);
cd '..';

max_dimension = 3; 
max_filtration_value = 1000; 
num_divisions = 10000;
options.max_filtration_value = max_filtration_value;
options.max_dimension = max_dimension - 1;

%------------------------------------------------------------
parfor i=1:10
         maColonne = mat(i,:); 
         intervals= Calcul_interval(maColonne,options,max_dimension, max_filtration_value, num_divisions)
         intervals 
         multinterval{i}= intervals;    
 end
```

i have this error : is not serializable.

Comment: Is that the complete error message?

Comment: You still get the error if you remove the line that should display the intervals? (i.e. the line that has only `intervals` on it)?

Comment: A complete code example we could actually run would help.

Comment: this line is just to display the interval, if i remove it i dont get this error message but the multinterval{i} array stay empty

Comment: Try to give a [mcve] and I will take a closer look at it.

Comment: Hello Daniel ; This is  a github the link to the library : https://github.com/appliedtopology/javaplex . and this the input matrix : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3uM9Np2kJYoTmtkRHV2WU5JeGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is i link for the first function : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3uM9Np2kJYoV184OVJuZGhlNFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i edit my question with complete and verifiable exemple.thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it reproduced. It can not be serialized because your variable `intervals` is holding an object of type `edu.stanford.math.plex4.homology.barcodes.BarcodeCollection` which is not serializable. You have to make it serializable or extract the relevant data on the workers. The parallel computing toolbox can only transport data which can be serialized.

Comment: thank you for your reply;
since the library is on github, can i make edu.stanford.math.plex4.homology.barcodes.BarcodeCollection serializable.. and how can i extract the relevant data on the workers?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with these objects. From the "toString()" it looks like it's just storing some intervals, so you could store it in some other data structure.

Comment: Hello;
I succeed to run the loop by storing the "intervals" in a matrix, but for execute  a computing parallel,  i have i7 with 4 cores I7 cpu 3.20 GHZ , i when i run the command  feature('numCores')
MATLAB detected: 3 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 6 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 6 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 3 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.

ans =

     3 how can I do to use all cores; thank you very much @Daniel

Comment: @ensberg: That's a different question and I can't answer it right now. I recommend to ask a now question, and include the model number of your CPU. It's something like i5-4690 CPU @ 3.50 Ghz (just an example). If this question is solved, please [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question.

Comment: i accepted your answer, thank you again for your help  :)